# How to set data source of hosted combobox

Tags: winforms, combobox

I am using a `ToolStripControlHost` to popup various other controls such as datagridviews, listviews, etc.. How do you assign a datasource to a combobox that is hosted in this manner. Setting the datasource using dataview, datatable, etc does not work. Does anyone know the secret or is this impossible?

Comment: Can you paste some example code and explain exactly what you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ToolStripComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.aspx) does not support data binding so you'll need to add the items by hand. Thankfully, the combo box has a name on the form so you can just do this:

```
toolStripComboBox.Items.AddRange(
    new object[]
    {
        "Value 1",
        "Value 2",
        etc.
    }
```

I don't know what you named the combo box, but just put that name in place of `toolStripComboBox`.

### Update for `ComboBox` Property

If you wanted to bind via the `ComboBox` property then you should be able to do something like this:

```
var cb = toolStripComboBox.ComboBox;
cb.ValueMember = "some field or property";
cb.DisplayMember = "some field or property";
cb.DataSource = {some IEnumerable<T> or DataView or some other sort of bindable list}
```

Comment: Using ComboBox not ToolStripComboBox. Actuall tried the ToolStripComboxBox and it doesnt work either. The toolstripcomboxbox has a combobox property and it will bind on the form but i  can find the how to do it in a dropdown/popup